# Access Denied_Just Install MySQL

Tags: java, passwords, mysql, eclipse, root

it's been 2 days and I still can't figure out why my I can't connect to MySQL on my command line. I am on a Mac and installed MySQL 8.0.17, Connect J 8.0.17 and Workbench 8.0.17. I need MySQL to complete my homework assignment which is to create a JDBC program that connects to the server. However, before I even started creating my program in Eclipse, I checked to make sure I could access MySQL server via cmd line (instructions from my professor) and it gives me this error message every time:

Kiaras-MBP:~ kiara$ /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Sometimes it will give me this one: 
Kiaras-MBP:~ kiara$ /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'kiara'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

I reset the password like I've read in some of theses forums (-u root -p), I've accessed root using -skip-grant and so much more. I've uninstalled/reinstalled and deleted all of MySQL and Eclipse form my computer multiple times. What am I doing wrong? I am also very knew to coding and therefore I may be a bit slow in understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Have a try with the following command:

```bsh
mysql_secure_installation
```

If you have installed mysql trough app manager (not compiled from source), you need to initializate the DB/users/permissions.

NOTE:
During the `mysql_secure_installation` you can choose to delete or not delete the default table (used for test purpouse)

Have a look here for further information:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-16-04